# Calculate the integral $ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{z_0+t(z_1-z_0)-z} \,dt $.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, winding-number

Let $z, z_0, z_1$ be three different complex numbers.
I am trying to calculate the integral $ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{z_0+t(z_1-z_0)-z} \,dt $. Is there a closed form? Any hints? Thank you.

Comment: Notice that $z_0+(z_1-z_0)t=(1-t)z_0+z_1t$. For $0\le t\le1$, $w=(1-t)z_0+z_1t$ parameterizes the straight-line path $C$ from $z_0$ to $z_1$, so the integral is equivalent to
$$\frac1{z_1-z_0}\int_C\frac{\mathrm dw}{w-z}$$

Comment: Yes, I know. That is precisely why I want to calculate it.